# How can I use an Apple system icon as a tab icon in Xamarin.Forms iOS custom renderer?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I came across this guide:

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/system-icons/

I would like to use some of these icons. Is there a way to do that or do I have to search for my own similar looking icons pngs and use them?

Note that I would be okay to use a custom renderer if that's the way that I should be doing it.  I am new to Xamarin and would appreciate any advice on how this could be done.

Here's an example of my custom renderer. But I still do not understand how to use the System icons:

```
    private void OnTabBarReselected(object sender, UITabBarSelectionEventArgs e)
    {
        //PhrasesFrameRendererClass frame = new PhrasesFrameRendererClass();
        var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;
        var playTab = tabs.Children[0];
        if (TabBar.SelectedItem.Title == "Play")
        {
            if (tabs != null)
            {
                playTab.Title = "Pause";
                playTab.Icon = "pause.png";
                playTab.Icon =  UITabBarSystemItem.Featured;
            }
            AS.runCardTimer = true;
        }
        else if (TabBar.SelectedItem.Title == "Pause")
        {
            if (tabs != null)
            {
                playTab.Title = "Play";
                playTab.Icon = "play.png";
                AS.phrasesFrame.SetTimerLabel("paused");
            }
            AS.runCardTimer = false;
        }

    }
```

Here's how I assign the icons. I would like to do this also in a custom renderer if that is possible:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var phrasesPage = new NavigationPage(new PhrasesPage())
        {
            Title = "Pause",
            Icon = "pause.png"
        };
        var settingsPage = new NavigationPage(new SettingsPage())
        {
            Title = "Settings",
            Icon = "settings.png"
        };
        var aboutPage = new NavigationPage(new AboutPage())
        {
            Title = "About",
            Icon = "info.png"
        };
        var categoriesPage = new NavigationPage(new CategoryGroupPage())
        {
            Title = "Cards",
            Icon = "tab.png"
        };

        Children.Add(phrasesPage);
        Children.Add(categoriesPage);
        Children.Add(settingsPage);
        Children.Add(aboutPage);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom renderer for your page. In my example it is CustomTabsPage class. You cannot just use system icons to create a UIImage. We need to use UITabBarItem. The problem is that UITabBarItem doesn't allow to change neither title nor image/icon. But we can copy an image from it.

```
using ButtonRendererDemo;
using ButtonRendererDemo.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomTabsPage), typeof(CustomTabsPageRenderer))]
namespace ButtonRendererDemo.iOS
{
    public class CustomTabsPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {

         #region Sytem Image with custom title

        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            foreach (var item in TabBar.Items)
            {
                item.Image = GetTabIcon(item.Title);
            }
        }

        private UIImage GetTabIcon(string title)
        {
            UITabBarItem item = null;

            switch (title)
            {
                case "Profile":
                    item = new UITabBarItem(UITabBarSystemItem.Search, 0);
                    break;
                case "Settings":
                    item = new UITabBarItem(UITabBarSystemItem.Bookmarks, 0);
                    break;
            }

            var img = (item != null) ? UIImage.FromImage(item.SelectedImage.CGImage, item.SelectedImage.CurrentScale, item.SelectedImage.Orientation) : new UIImage();
            return img;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Yuri,  Can you give a bit more than the one line as I am not really sure where to start with a custom renderer. Thanks

Comment: You will need custom renderer for the page. You will have an access to UIController in it

Comment: Can you please consider adding some lines of code to explain. I'm sorry but I still don't understand how to do this in the custom renderer

Comment: Lets start with what are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to avoid using png icons in the tab areas and would like to replace them with some of the Apple UI system-icons. If those icons are png's then I could use them but I don't know where the Apple icons come from or if there are png versions of them somewhere.  My workmate found another unanswered SO question out there and added a 500 bonus to it.  Pretty much same question.  You might want to have a look.

Comment: In the question your workmate shows what I showed here - is iOS implementation and he is asking how to do it in cross-platform. The answer is you can do it in iOS but cannot use Apple System icons in Android

Comment: We would like to see the iOS custom renderer solution and then hope to do another Droid custom renderer using png

Comment: I am still fighting a problem. When I use UITabBarSystemItem I cannot set title text, it t by iOS automatically. Not sure if it is by design or a bug. Is that a problem?

Comment: ok. unfortunately you cannot change title if you use UITabBarSystemItem. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarsystemitem "The title and image of system tab bar items cannot be changed."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560305/can-one-use-system-icons-on-tabs-in-xamarin-forms    500 bonus on this if you can do more research :-)